# How return $this->address[$type] ?? []; work?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

I just encounter a syntax expression while working with laravel model.

```
  public function address($type)
    {
        return $this->address[$type] ?? [];
    }
```

I don't understand how does this

```
 return $this->address[$type] ?? [];
```

Work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference — What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the null coalescing operation (see more at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_coalescing_operator#PHP). It's a syntactic shortcut for `isset`, really:

```
return $this->address[$type] ?? [];
```

can be read as:

```
if (isset($this->address[$type])) {
  return $this->address[$type];
} else {
  return [];
}
```

Comment: Should note that this operation is only available in PHP 7+.